# Compact sequence space with alternative metric

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, compactness

Let us set $\ell := \left \lbrace (x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^\infty(\mathbb{R}): \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert x_k \rvert \leq 1 \right \rbrace$ and equip it with the metric $d: \ell^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \times \ell^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$, where
$$
d(x, y) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\lvert x_k - y_k \rvert}{(k+1)^3}.
$$

I want to prove that $\ell$ is compact as a subset of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. Is the following correct?

Assume $\left(x^{(j)} \right)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \ell$ is a sequence. Then, because $\lvert x^{(j)}_k \rvert$ is uniformly bounded by $1$ in $j$ and $k$, by the diagonal argument, we can find a subsequence $(x^{(n_j)})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$  such that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $x_k \in \mathbb{R}$ with
$$
\left \lvert x_k^{(n_j)} - x_k \right \rvert \overset{j \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}0.
$$
Clearly, $\lvert x_k \rvert \leq 1$ for all $k$. Now let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary and $m \in \mathbb{N}$ so big such that $\displaystyle \sum_{k = m+1}^\infty \frac{2}{(k+1)^3} < \varepsilon$. Let $x := (x_k)_{k \in\mathbb{N}} \in \ell$. Thus
$$
d(x^{(n_j)}, x) < \sum_{k = 1}^m \frac{\lvert x_k^{(n_j)} - x_k \rvert}{(k+1)^3} + \varepsilon
$$
and therefore
$$
\limsup_{j \rightarrow \infty} d(x^{(n_j)}, x) \leq \varepsilon.
$$
by definition of $x$.
Letting $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ we can see that $x$ is the desired convergent subsequence.

Comment: The assertion “as a a subset of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb R)$” makes no sense: Either you consider it with the metric $d$ or with the metric inherited from the norm of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb R)$. In the former case, it is compact (and it seems to me that your proof for this is correct). In the latter case it fails to be compact.